# `Index.php` file Showing Code and not Rendering a Website

Tags: php, html, netbeans

I don't know how to explain this very well, I'm sure its something pretty dumb..
First of all, I'm using netbeans in linux.
I am trying to write a simple website with some links and a menu. For the menu I'm using GET variables to know what page to include. I want to do the include with php so I needed to insert some php code in the html file. I red that I need to change the filename to index.php for the server to recognize php commands.. So I changed the file extension to php and now I only see the code of the website and not the website itself..

This is my index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Ishimoto - Cars for life</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="allwebsite">
            <div id="menu">
                <div id="logo">
                    <a href="?nav=index"><img src="img/logo.jpg" width="450" alt="LOGO"/></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <?php
                    echo $_GET['nav'];
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I configured apache and php is running fine if I run it from outside netbeans, but when I run the project from netbeans, I still get the source code.
it is running through:

```
http://localhost:8383/Ishimoto/index.php
```

Any thought?

Comment: What does your index.php look like?

Comment: If you solved your problem, it could be useful to others if you wrote what your problem was and how you solved it, as answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Linux, execute `sudo a2enmod php5` then restart apache `sudo service apache2 restart` or `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: So what does your vhost configuration file look like?

Comment: The problem was in my apache configuration.. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

My problem was actually 2 problems. First of all my apache wasn't installed correctly so I re installed it: `sudo apt-get install apache2` and then re installed php5: `sudo apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5`. After that I had to move the project to my /var/www/ folder and work on that. And thats it!
Thanks all!